# How to list modified files in multiple git in all sub directory in android source code?

Tags: android, git, android-source

I am working on Android open source project. I have made several changes in multiple sub directorates of AOSP. These files fall under different git. So, is there any method to list all these modified files all together?

Answer (score 2):

AOSP uses repo tool

use

repo status
repo diff
repo info

Create a new topic branch using

repo start foobar

Answer (score 0):

If those "different git" are submodules within AOSP, then you can use:

```
git submodule foreach "git status"
```

To list only modified files:

```
git submodule foreach "git ls-files -m"
```

or

```
git submodule foreach "git diff --name-only"
```